# Django PasswordChangeView throws "The password is too similar to the email address." error

Tags: python, django

I trying to create URL where users can change their passwords. This error is kinda weird, because I don't even have field for email in my registration form. In my registration form I asked user only for `username` and `password`. Also, I don't change standart `User` model.

---

If someone need any code parts to help me, write what do you need. I don't even know what should I attach because have no idea what is going wrong.

UPD 1:
Thanks to `py_dude` for useful links. I got it. For anyone with same problem, I'l leave solution that worked for me.

Go to project's root `urls.py`. Then, find `AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS` list, and update dictionary which has `django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator` key with next values:

```
'OPTIONS': {
    'user_attributes': ('username', 'first_name', 'last_name')
}
```

Also you can leave only username, or any of these fields.
For a complete picture, I attach what I have at the end:

```
AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
        'OPTIONS': {
            'user_attributes': ('username')
        }
    },
    ...
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disable it for development period:

https://stumbles.id.au/disabling-djangos-password-strength-checking-for-development.html

From the docs:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/_modules/django/contrib/auth/password_validation/#UserAttributeSimilarityValidator

If you want to disable it at all, you can reassign

`DEFAULT_USER_ATTRIBUTES = ('username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email')` inside `UserAttributeSimilarityValidator` class

Comment: Just now I created file `validators.py`, and override this class there. But error is still here. What I'm doing wrong?